# using pandas merge for two csv based on two columns, getting KeyError: 'player_name'

Tags: python, pandas, merge

i'm trying to merge two CSVs, one which contain player data from college basketball ncaab and one from nba for years 2018-2021, there are 54 columns in the ncaab database which have all the player stats, whereas there are 3 columns in nba that have player_name, height and one column with value true. there may be some data that is not common between, and i just want to keep the ncaab database merged with only the common data with the nba one.

```
data1 = pd.read_csv('ncaab18-21c.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('tonba2018-21.csv')
  

output1 = pd.merge(data1, data2, 
                   on=['player_name','height'],
                   how='left')
  

#output1.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
output1.to_csv ('final.csv')
```

Comment: from pandas.merge docs : on = Column or index level names to join on. These must be found in both DataFrames. I don't understand why you would include 'height' in the _on_ list, unless you have 2 players with the same name, but different heights that you are trying to distinguish between. Also, as the error is informing you 'player_name' is perhaps missing from one of your datframes. Confirm column names using data1.columns and data2.columns to see the column names.

Comment: Following on from bici.sancta, if the columns names are different in the two dataframes, use `left_on` and `right_on` to specify for each.

Comment: `output1 = pd.merge(data1, data2)` should be what you need.

Comment: @not_speshal, hey I don't just need to merge them, I need to merge them on basis of names, but just the merge, merges the different players in one row.

Comment: Post samples of both your dataframes and your expected output.